# leaflet. функция flyTo в forEach срабатывает один раз,хотя должна больше, в чем проблема

Tags: javascript, json, leafletjs

у меня есть функция, при вызове программа приближается к каждому объекту на карте каждые несколько секунд, в console.log она как раз и срабатывает нужные 219 раз, но на экране приближается только к одному обьекту, в чем проблема

```
function Presentation(json) {

    array=json.features;

      array.forEach(item=>{
  console.log('start');
           setTimeout(
    ()=> {
 mymap.flyTo([item.geometry.coordinates[1],item.geometry.coordinates[0]],10);
    },2000)

        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может `array.forEach( item  => {`, а не `function(item) {`.

---

`forEach((item,i)=>` ... `2000*(i+1)`

Comment: к сожалению нет

Comment: В программе написано: приблизиться ко всем элементам через 2с

Comment: может время таймаута завит он номера item-a

Comment: Сработало, спасибо, но можно поподробнее, как время таймаута может зависить от item'a?

Comment: Весь `forEach` отрабатывает моментально для всех итемов. Он ставит много заданий `setTimeout(что_сделать,когда)` на разное время

Comment: В `forEach((item,i)=>` в `i` попадает номер итема в массиве от 0; 2000*(0+1)=2000 мс от текущего момента для первого итема и на 2000мс больше дла каждого следующего

Comment: Спасибо еще раз